# Can I merge two requirements.txt files to one via Docker compose?

Tags: python, docker-compose

I have multiple python microservices, that all have separate requirements, but share some requirements and some code. I mount this shared code and requirements.txt to every service in a volume specified by a docker-compose file.

Example, where the two mounted volumes have different requirements.txt files:

```
  search:
    build: ./services/search
    volumes:
      - ./services/search:/app
      - ./shared:/app/shared
    command: python search.py

  filter:
    build: ./services/filter
    volumes:
      - ./services/filter:/app
      - ./shared:/app/shared
    command: python filter.py
```

Is there a way to merge the two requirements.txt files? At the moment, I run two separate `pip -r install requirements.txt` commands, but I don't like that approach.

Comment: I think doing two separate `pip` runs is the best approach. There is no penalty of having requirements to split over several files.

Answer (score -3):

I see no reason why running the command twice isn't good, but you can also merge `requirements1.txt` into `requirements2.txt` using `cat requirements1.txt >> requirements2.txt`

Comment: On the `cat` solution, what happens when one requirements file has different granularity than the other on the same library? Or even conflicting versions? Running `pip` twice doesn't completely solve the issue, but it won't necessarily blow up.